# Executing JavaScript on a specific website using a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

To improve my workflow I'm trying to create a small Chrome extension that will run a JS script on a website that contains a specific string in the URL. I've never worked with JS and I'm a rather inexperienced hobbyist, so this code may make little to no sense.

The onInstalled event is executed without an issue, but I can't get onUpdated to trigger properly.

Here are all of the files:

hide.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    console.log('Extension initialized');
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        var activeTab = tabs[0];
        var tabUrl = activeTab.url;
     });
     if(tabUrl.includes('website')){
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: {tabId: activeTab.id}, function: code()});
     }
});
function code(){
    console.log('code executed')
}
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Hide",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "hide.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "scripting"]
}
```

Comment: If you just want to run custom JS, a [userscript](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) might be a bit easier to get running right-out-of-the-box

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks a lot, never thought that an extension like this may exist. I will take a look into this and while it may solve my issue, I'd still like to get this extension working, just for the learning sake.

Comment: There are two mistakes: 1) don't use query, use the parameters passed to [onUpdated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) listener, 2) It's asynchronous so you must use the value inside the callback. Anyway there's a much simpler solution which is to remove the background script and declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) instead.